# Vticker and Sharrre jQuery plugins not working at same time

Tags: jquery, plugins, social-networking

I've got the code:

```
$('#newsSocialTicker').rssfeed('http://something/feed/',{
snippet: true,
titletag: 'h3'
}, function(e) {
$(e).find('div.rssBody').vTicker({ showItems: 2});
});
/*
$('#shareIcon').click(function(e) {
// prevent the browser from following the link
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();

$dialog.load('socialActivity.jsp');
$dialog.dialog( "option", "title", "Share Page" );
$dialog.dialog('open');

});
*/
```

When I run it, I've got no errors (but code in bottom is as comment).

If I uncomment the bottom code, I get:

```
$(e).find("div.rssBody").vTicker is not a function
```

I don't know if it's important, but the code in 'socialActivity.jsp' is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/js/jquery.sharrre-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery/js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function() {       
    // social buttons
    $('#sharemediv').sharrre({
        ...
    });       
});   // END function()        
</script>

<div id="sharemediv">
    ...
</div>
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code present at your question, the error:

```
$(e).find("div.rssBody").vTicker is not a function
```

Is due to the fact that you are not including the **vTicker** plug-in!

Or if you are, that doesn't show on your question, you are including it after calling for it.

Comment: I'm loading the plugin! If I was not, the first part of code should show the same error. As I said, with some code as comments, the vTicker runs well. I begin page loading 'jQuery.js', 'zrssfeed.js' and 'vticker.js'.

Comment: Try changing `$('#shareIcon').click(function(e) {` to `$('#shareIcon').click(function(event) {` and replace `e` by `event` on the next two lines... it may be a conflict by having the same variable for two different scenarios.

Comment: I changed that variable name, but it not solved the problem. I think it is something in pages loaded from the parent page. May be the javascript files loaded in that new pages, but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: If none page is loaded from the parent page, the plugin runs well. If 'socialActivity.jsp' or other page are loaded, the error appears.

Comment: Well, I think it is solved. I was loading 'jquery.js' in the new pages again! It is not needed, if the page is loaded from a parent one. Thank you for your help.